# SQL Server Dynamic SQL - Get output from list of tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I am trying to loop through a temp table variable that contains a list of table names.  I want to simply count the rows in each table where a DateTracked column is greater than 30 days.  I am having trouble dynamically changing the FROM @tblName variable to store the record count and then insert it into my tracking table.  Eventually I will use a cursor to loop through each, but I just want to get this logic down first for a single table.  Here is my test code:

```
DECLARE @tblName as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @q as NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @q = 'Select Count(DateTracked) FROM Audit.' + @tblName + ' WHERE DateTracked > DATEADD(dd, -30, CAST(GETDATE() as date))'

--DECLARE @tblNameTable TABLE
--(
--  tableName NVARCHAR(MAX)
--)
--INSERT INTO @tblNameTable VALUES (N'myTestTable')

DECLARE @ExpectedRecordsToMove AS TABLE (col1 int)
INSERT INTO @ExpectedRecordsToMove EXECUTE sp_executesql @q, N'@tblName nvarchar(500)', @tblName = 'myTestTable'

SELECT * FROM @ExpectedRecordsToMove
```

Comment: You cannot parameterize `@q` since you cannot parameterize table names even in dynamic SQL; the *whole statement* must be generated dynamically, since `@tblName` must be interpolated into the text. If you set `@tblName` before producing `@q` you have the same effect as you'd have in a loop.

Comment: No, that's precisely what will *not* work. Again, table names cannot be parameters. `'SELECT ...' + @tblName + ' WHERE ...'` is correct, but then `@tblName` must already have a value there, and should not be passed as a parameter. In your example, `DECLARE @tblName AS SYSNAME = 'myTestTable'`.

Comment: I understand now.  How can I take the output of sp_executesql once I have that statement generated and insert it into a variable that I can reference?

Comment: Not sure what the question is there -- `INSERT ... EXEC` works with table variables, so the remainder of the code is fine. The `INSERT` of course should not happen inside the dynamically generated statement, as then you can't reference the outer scope's variables.

Comment: I understand now.  I was declaring a local variable and NOT a temp table variable.  It seems to work now.

Comment: Please don't post answers on the questions section. You can post answer to your own question in the answer section and accept that.

Answer (score 4):

Found solution.

```
DECLARE @tblName as NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'tblAutoDispatch_DispatchStatus_Map_Tracking'
DECLARE @q as NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT Count(DateTracked) FROM Audit.' + @tblName + ' WHERE DateTracked > DATEADD(dd, -30, CAST(GETDATE() as date))'

DECLARE @ExpectedRecordsToMove TABLE
(
    ExpectedRecordsToMove Int
)
INSERT INTO @ExpectedRecordsToMove
EXECUTE sp_executesql @q

SELECT * FROM @ExpectedRecordsToMove
```

<sub>Note: Answer provided by OP on question.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

`sp_executesql` also allows for output parameters. It is possible to assign variable inside the inner query and return the value.

```
DECLARE @tblName AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'tblAutoDispatch_DispatchStatus_Map_Tracking';
DECLARE @q AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
    = N'SELECT @rowcount = COUNT(DateTracked) FROM Audit.' + @tblName
      + N' WHERE DateTracked > DATEADD(dd, -30, CAST(GETDATE() as date))';

DECLARE @rowcount INT;

EXECUTE sp_executesql
    @query = @q,
    @parameters = N'@rowcount INT OUTPUT',
    @rowcount = @rowcount OUTPUT;

SELECT
    @rowcount;
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can actually do this without a cursor, by building up the query in one go**

- You must use `QUOTENAME` to ensure table names do not cause syntax errors
- You cannot parameterize a table name, it must be inserted directly into dynamic SQL

```sql
DECLARE @tablenames TABLE (schemaName sysname, tblName sysname);
--  insert schema and table names

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
SELECT
    ISNULL(tblName, ''Grand Total'') AS tblName,
    SUM(rowcount) AS rowcount
FROM (
' +
(
  SELECT STRING_AGG(CAST(
N'    SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(tn.schemaName, '''') + N'.' + QUOTENAME(tn.tblName, '''') + N' AS tblName,
           Count(DateTracked) AS rowCount
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(tn.schemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(tn.tblName) + N'
    WHERE DateTracked > DATEADD(dd, -30, CAST(GETDATE() as date))'
  AS nvarchar(max)), N'
UNION ALL
')
  FROM @tablenames tn
  JOIN sys.tables t ON tn.schemaName = SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) AND tn.tblName = t.name
) + N'
) AS tables
GROUP BY ROLLUP(tblName);
';

PRINT @sql;  -- for testing
EXEC (@sql);
```

- If you don't have `STRING_AGG` on your version of SQL Server, you must use `FOR XML` instead

Comment: I didn't describe this in the original post, but I'm using a cursor to loop through 200 tables and a WHILE LOOP to batch the deletes/OUTPUT so I'm okay using a cursor in this scenario since there is no performance impact and I am still using a SET based operation for my actual transactions.