# SQL - Select from Multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, multiple-databases

I have 10 databases all in the same instance and schema with identical tables.

Looking to create a `SELECT` query which can use a variable of the database names and return all of the records into a single dataset.

I've been looking around and put the following together as a test (the real select statement is much larger with multiple joins)

This test does work but it returns two result sets one for each database.

Is there a way to combine the results into one set or am I using the wrong approach?

Thanks in advance

```
DECLARE @DB_NAME VARCHAR(6);

DECLARE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT name
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE name IN ('CN2DAT', 'AU1DAT') 

OPEN CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES

FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES INTO @DB_NAME

WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC ('SELECT * FROM ' + @DB_NAME + '.dbo.ICITEM')

    -- EXEC ('USE '+ @DB_NAME + ' SELECT * from dbo.ICITEM')

    FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES INTO @DB_NAME
END

CLOSE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES
```

Comment: I think that is because of in ('CN2DAT', 'AU1DAT')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server Dynamic SQL - Get output from list of tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67369265/sql-server-dynamic-sql-get-output-from-list-of-tables) Although needing to do this in the first place is a sign of bad design

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a view which combines the select statements. e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW v_ICITEM
AS
SELECT * FROM CN2DAT.dbo.ICITEM
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM AU1DAT.dbo.ICITEM
go;
```

You could include the source database as a column also:

```
CREATE VIEW v_ICITEM
AS
SELECT 'CN2DAT' AS Db, * FROM CN2DAT.dbo.ICITEM
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'AU1DAT', * FROM AU1DAT.dbo.ICITEM
go;
```

Comment: I just tried the view approach with UNION ALL on the real query. It gives the desired results but is pretty big and would be a nightmare to maintain especially when including all 10 databases

Comment: @ColinA unfortunately you have a bad situation and there is not going to be a good, easy to maintain T-SQL solution for this. Cross-database queries should be avoided in general, and if you ask me your issue is more of a design issue than anything. This solution is the simplest T-SQL solution. Otherwise you are left with dynamic SQL solutions (like the OP), which is an even worse solution. IMO if you need to query multiple databases then that work should be done in a separate application and not in a single T-SQL script.

Comment: What you can do is create scripts that generate the views.  If you add a new database - regenerate the views.  The real question is why do you need to do this?

Comment: Hi All, Thanks for your comments. I agree the overall design is lacking. The purpose of the script is to gather sales data for our various entities for reporting purposes, which ideally we would have in a separate consolidated company database. Unfortunately proper consolidation is not an option at the moment. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Marking Zeph's answer as correct because I will do the following.
Create views in each DB which will be identical then create a parent view to UNION all the subordinates. This works, but not ideal given the lack of consolidation/poor design. At least I can maintain one subordinate view and duplicate it

Answer (score 1):

Store the results into a temp table eg:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempICITEM 
    ([DbName] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [ICITEMId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL)
```

Change your TSQL select to an Insert Into #TempTable Select eg:

```
EXEC ('INSERT INTO #TempICITEM ([DbName],[ICITEMId],[Name],[Description]) SELECT ''' + @DB_NAME + ''' DbName,[DbName],[ICITEMId],[Name],[Description] FROM ' + @DB_NAME + '.dbo.ICITEM')
```

Then Select from the combine results of the temp table eg:

```
SELECT * From #TempICITEM
```

And all together:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempICITEM 
    ([DbName] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [ICITEMId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](1000) NOT NULL)

DECLARE @DB_NAME VARCHAR(6);
DECLARE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES CURSOR FOR 
SELECT name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name IN ('CN2DAT', 'AU1DAT') 

OPEN CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES INTO @DB_NAME
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
BEGIN
EXEC ('INSERT INTO #TempICITEM ([DbName],[ICITEMId],[Name],[Description]) SELECT ''' + @DB_NAME + ''' DbName,[DbName],[ICITEMId],[Name],[Description] FROM ' + @DB_NAME + '.dbo.ICITEM')
FETCH NEXT FROM CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES INTO @DB_NAME
END

CLOSE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES
DEALLOCATE CURSOR_ALLDB_NAMES

SELECT * From #TempICITEM
```

Comment: Note too that it doesn't have to be a temporary table.  You could make it a permanent one too, just don't forget to add the Database Name as a column so you know the source database of each record.